# Make rsync exclude all directories that contain a file with a specific name

Tags: rsync, data-synchronization

I would like rsync to exclude all directories that contain a file with a specific name, say ".rsync-exclude", independent of the contents of the ".rsync-exclude" file.

If the file ".rsync-exclude" contained just "*", I could use `rsync -r SRC DEST --filter='dir-merge,- .rsync-exclude'`.

However, the directory should be excluded independent of the contents of the ".rsync-exclude" file (it should at least be possible to leave the ".rsync-exclude" file empty).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rsync does not support this (at least the manpage does not mention anything), but you can do it in two steps:

1. run `find` to find the `.rsync-exclude` files
2. pipe this list to `--exclude-from` (or use a temporary file)

   ```
      --exclude-from=FILE
         This option is related to the --exclude option, but it specifies a FILE that contains exclude  patterns
         (one per line).  Blank lines in the file and lines starting with ';' or '#' are ignored.  If FILE is -,
         the list will be read from standard input.
   ```

alternatively, if you do not mind to put something in the files, you can use:

```
       -F     The -F option is a shorthand for adding two --filter rules to your command.  The first time it is  used
          is a shorthand for this rule:

             --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'

          This  tells  rsync  to  look for per-directory .rsync-filter files that have been sprinkled through the
          hierarchy and use their rules to filter the files in the transfer.  If -F is repeated, it is  a  short-
          hand for this rule:

             --filter='exclude .rsync-filter'

          This filters out the .rsync-filter files themselves from the transfer.

          See the FILTER RULES section for detailed information on how these options work.
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I had the same one..

You can add the following filter:

```
--filter="dir-merge,n- .rsync-exclude"
```

Now you can place a .rsync-exclude file in any folder and write the names of the files and folders you want to exclude line by line. for example:

```
#.rsync-exclude file

folderYouWantToExclude
allFilesThatStartWithXY*
someSpecialImage.png
```

So you can use patterns in there too.

What you can't do is:

```
#.rsync-exclude file

folder/someFileYouWantToExlude
```

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Should that be `n-` or `-n` in the `--filter="dir-merge,n- .rsync-exclude"`? What dos the `n` do?

Comment: @GiffordN. to be honest, this is too long ago and I also don't find the answer right now, sry :/ But I would guess it defines the file that rsync should use in each folder for filtering.

Comment: I found it, it should be `n-` as described in the FILTER RULES section of the rsync man pages. Additionally, the _`n` specifies that the rules are not inherited by subdirectories._ and the `-` means that the _rules that are read in from the file default to having the exclude modifier set_, e.g. `dir-merge,n- .non-inherited-per-dir-excludes`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `tar` instead of pure `rsync`, then you can use the `tar --exclude-tag=FILE` option. This obviously doesn't get the incremental backup benefits of rsync, so it may not be exactly what you're looking for.

```
tar cv --exclude-tag=.rsync-exclude ...
```

Answer (score -3):

```
rsync -avz --exclude 'dir' /source /destination
```

Comment: Please, add a short description in the answer to help users understand

Comment: This does not address the question.